# Multi-line ssh where results need to be saved

Tags: bash, ssh, redis

I have a script where I have the following code:

`results=$(ssh $server 'keys=$(redis-cli scan 0) ; keypairs=""  ; for key in $keys ; do value=$(redis-cli get $key) ; keypairs="$keypairs$key $value\n" ; done ; echo $keypairs')`

This code works, but it is rather ugly to look at so I am trying to perform this on multiple lines and I can't quite figure out how it should be done.

I have tried

```
results=$(ssh $server "
keys=$(redis-cli scan 0)
keypairs=\"\"
for key in $keys
do
value=$(redis-cli get $key)
keypairs=\"$keypairs$key $value\n\"
done
echo $keypairs
")
```

But this returns the error `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`. The weird thing is that the error shows up *before* it even has asked for the credentials for ssh:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
host@server's password:
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here and how I should go about having this section be a multi-line?

Comment: You can feed the script in stdin of ssh, but that will only work if you are not using a password to authenticate. Your example example runs redis on your local machine before calling ssh due to the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A multiline command can be used to assign to a variable, such as:

```
multilinecommand=$(test=check
if [ $test == "check" ]
then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
)
```

where `echo $multilinecommand` shows `Yes`.

If you however want to split a *single* command into multiple lines, you have to add a backslash at the end of the line to denote that the command isn't finished yet. Your command therefore becomes:

```
results=$(ssh $server " \
keys=$(redis-cli scan 0) \
keypairs=\"\" 
for key in $keys
do
value=$(redis-cli get $key)
keypairs=\"$keypairs$key $value\n\"
done
echo $keypairs
")
```

because keys and keypairs are needed for the ssh command